# Scala ListBuffer prevents potential for stack overflow?

Tags: scala

In section 17.1 (Collections) of Programming in Scala (Martin Odersky), there is a line which says:

> Another reason to use `ListBuffer` instead of `List` is to prevent the potential for stack overflow.

How does using a `ListBuffer` prevents the potential for stack overflow? ...No pun intended ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The book itself gives [the answer](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html):

> If you can build a list in the desired order by prepending, but the recursive algorithm that would be required is not tail recursive, you can use a for expression or while loop and a ListBuffer instead.

[An example](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implementing-lists.html#sec:the-listbuffer-class) is given for a function that increments every element of a `List` without using the `map` function.

```
def incAllUnsafe(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
  case List() => List()
  case x :: xs1 => x + 1 :: incAllUnsafe(xs1)
}

def incAllSafe(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val buf = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
  for (x <- xs) buf += x + 1
  buf.toList
}
```